# Dart testing - what is the correct syntax to tag a test and run it?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have my test like this with a tag

```
main() {
  test("testing wether test works", () async {
    expect(true, true);
  }, tags: 'testme');
}
```

...and I'm running it like so, specifying only the tagged tests

```
pub run test --tags "testme"
```

When I run it, all the tests run in my project, not just the tagged ones, is this the correct syntax and command to run?

Comment: I tried your code, and `pub run test --tags "testme"` worked for me, running only that single test and none of the others it normally runs from the `test/` directory.  I'm using `package:test` v1.14.0 if that matters.

Comment: thank you, yes I worked out I had another unrelated error which meant the tests were not running correctly. I've added an answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it works just as in the question.  My problem was that another error was occuring